# How to save last components changes?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

There is component that is activated by condition ngif.

Use can perform activity, for example open menu, set active element or just write text inside textarea.

After that user leaves this component to another ngif.

After time user returns to previous component.

How to restore last activity, components changes to continue work?

I know, it might be solved using service, but mu component has it's own logic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with ngIf the component is destroyed and created based on the value. I think you should save the data in the host component in OnDestroy hook of the component in question, using @output and handling this event in host component, and use @input to pass in data to the component when you need to.

**ParentComponent HTML**

```
<app-child-component *ngIf="showThisComponent == 'comp1' " (saveData)="onSaveData($event)" [showData]="showThisData[comp1]" 
/>
```

**ParentComponent .ts**

```
onSomeAction() {
    this.showThisComponent = 'comp1';
}

onSaveData(data) {
    this.showThisData[comp1] = data;
}
```

**ChildComponent .ts**

```
@Input() showData: any;
@Output() saveData: new EventEmitter<any>();

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.saveData.emit(data);
}
```

You could do something on these lines I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ngIf` directive always destroy components that doesn't meet the condition, you should not use `ngIf`to "toggle" the components that storing live data inside without storing it somewhere else when it destroyed. I suggest to use CSS to toggle the components visibility instead.

```
<your-component [ngStyle]="{'display' : yourToggleExpressions ? 'none' : 'block'}"><your-component/>
```

This way, you hide it from UI while it still running behind.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the the `canDeactivated` guard it will call before the `ngOnDestroy`.

```
interface CanDeactivate<T> { 
   canDeactivate(component: T, 
      currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
      nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
}
```